# Powershell error. WriteToServer. column does not allow DBNull.Value

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am using following powershell script to collect server storage information from multiple servers and into the one of the SQL server table. 
I am getting an error while executing following powershell script

Error:-

> Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "Column
>   'server_name' does not allow DBNull.Value.

Table has only one column with all server names in it. Powershell script grabs server name from database table and collect server storage information. It works for few servers however it fails for few server with above error.

```
Table 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[server_space_lku](
    [server_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_server_lku] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
```

I am using following powershell script. How can I fix the issue?

```
    param($destServer, $destDb)

function Get-SqlData
{
    param([string]$serverName=$(throw 'serverName is required.'), [string]$databaseName=$(throw 'databaseName is required.'),
          [string]$query=$(throw 'query is required.'))

    Write-Verbose "Get-SqlData serverName:$serverName databaseName:$databaseName query:$query"

    $connString = "Server=$serverName;Database=$databaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    $da = New-Object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($query,$connString)
    $dt = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"
    [void]$da.fill($dt)
    $dt

} #Get-SqlData


function Get-Vol
{
    param($computerName)

    Get-WmiObject -computername "$ComputerName" Win32_Volume -filter "DriveType=3 AND SystemVolume = $false" | 
    foreach { add-member -in $_ -membertype noteproperty UsageDT $((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
              add-member -in $_ -membertype noteproperty SizeGB $([math]::round(($_.Capacity/1GB),2))
              add-member -in $_ -membertype noteproperty FreeGB $([math]::round(($_.FreeSpace/1GB),2))
              add-member -in $_ -membertype noteproperty PercentFree $([math]::round((([float]$_.FreeSpace/[float]$_.Capacity) * 100),2)) -passThru} |
    select UsageDT, SystemName, Name, Label, SizeGB, FreeGB, PercentFree

}# Get-Vol




function Out-DataTable 
{
    param($Properties="*")
    Begin
    {
        $dt = new-object Data.datatable  
        $First = $true 
    }
    Process
    {
        $DR = $DT.NewRow()  
        foreach ($item in $_ |  Get-Member -type *Property $Properties ) {  
          $name = $item.Name
          if ($first) {  
            $Col =  new-object Data.DataColumn  
            $Col.ColumnName = $name
            $DT.Columns.Add($Col)
          }  
            $DR.Item($name) = $_.$name  
        }  
        $DT.Rows.Add($DR)  
        $First = $false  
    }
    End
    {
        return @(,($dt))
    }

}# Out-DataTable 


function Write-DataTableToDatabase
{ 
    param($destServer,$destDb,$destTbl,$dt)

    $connectionString = "Data Source=$destServer;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$destdb;"
    $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $connectionString
    $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "$destTbl"
    $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt)

}# Write-DataTableToDatabase


Get-SqlData $destServer $destDb  "SELECT server_name FROM server_space_lku" |
foreach {
            #Get just the server name portion if instance name is included
            $computerName = $_.server_name -replace "\\.*|,.*"
            $dt = Get-Vol $computerName | Out-DataTable
            Write-DataTableToDatabase $destServer $destDb 'vol_space' $dt
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any server names that start with \ or \\ ? That regex replace in Get-SqlData would get rid of the whole string if that's the case.

Comment: No, I don't have server name start with \ or \\. All the server names like server1,server2,...

Comment: Based on the table name ```server_space_lku```, it looks like you're using a 3rd party capacity management script (see https://www.sqlshack.com/proactive-capacity-management/) - does your ```server_space_lku``` table have null values in the "server_name" column in any rows maybe?

Comment: That's right. I am using 3rd party capacity management script. Table 'server_space_lku' does not have null value. table has 40 server names. script works for 28 servers without any issue but it fails for remaining servers.

Comment: as a test, can you add something like ```write-host "server_name = '$($_.server_name)'"``` before ```$computerName = ...```, and ```write-host "computerName = '$computerName'"``` afterwards, and then see which value throws the exception?

Comment: I have list of server names that throws an error. There are 12 servers. Server returns volume information when I execute following command for the servers throwing an error but it does not work when try to get server name from the SQL table.  `Get-WmiObject -computername server1 Win32_Volume`